# Renumbering form input array after dynamically adding and removing fields

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I am creating a WordPress widget, and in the widget back-end I give the ability to add and remove blocks of input fields. I have the ability to add and remove working for the most part. My issue is when I try to renumber the field names so that they $_POST as a well formed array and never have duplicate indexes. Everything I have tried has only caused a different problem. The code I am currently working with is having issues that I can not nail down. Sometimes it seems that when I add a field the counter is being multiplied or something. And when I remove a block and recalculate and renumber the field the fields never go back to 0, or even 1. It feels like blocks are being counted more then once, or some are being counted even though they have been removed.

I tried to look at the source code to see if more blocks are being added then I want, but I guess blocks I add this way do not show up in the source code until the widget has been saved.

This is the Javascript being used to and, remove, and renumber.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    /*--start toplist_widget--*/
    function renumber_blocks() {
        jQuery(".eyenodtoplistitem li").each(function(index) {
            jQuery(this).find("input").each(function() {
               this.name = this.name.replace(/eyenod_toplist\[\d+\]/, "eyenod_toplist[" + index + "]");   
            });
            jQuery(".eyenodtoplistitem li input[type=hidden]").val(index);
        });
    }

    tl_count = 0;
    jQuery('.toplist-add').unbind('click').bind('click', function(e) {
        var appendhtml = '<li>' + 
                             '<div style="height:20px; background:#EAEAEA;"></div>' + 
                             '<input type="hidden" name="eyenod_toplist[' + tl_count + '][id]" value="' + tl_count + '" />' + 
                             '<label for="eyenod_toplist_imgurl">Image URL:</label><input class="widefat" type="text" name="eyenod_toplist[' + tl_count + '][imgurl]" value="" /><br />' + 
                             '<label for="eyenod_toplist_bonus">Bonus:</label><input class="widefat" type="text" name="eyenod_toplist[' + tl_count + '][bonus]" value="" /><br />' + 
                             '<label for="eyenod_toplist_link">Visit URL:</label><input class="widefat" type="text" name="eyenod_toplist[' + tl_count + '][link]" value="" /><br />' + 
                             '<a class="toplist-remove" href="javascript:void(0);">Delete</a>' + 
                         '</li>';

        jQuery('.eyenodtoplistitem').append(appendhtml);
        renumber_blocks();
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    jQuery(".eyenodtoplistitem").on("click", ".toplist-remove", function (e) {
        jQuery(this).closest("li").remove();
        renumber_blocks();
        e.preventDefault();
    });     
    /*--end toplist_widget--*/
});
```

And this is the form function for adding the widget to the system.

```
public function form( $instance ) {
    if (isset($instance['title'])) {
        $title = $instance['title'];
    } else {
        $title = __('Top List', 'eyenod');
    }

    $instance_eyenod_toplist = array();
    if(isset($instance['eyenod_toplist'])) {
        $instance_eyenod_toplist = unserialize($instance['eyenod_toplist']);
    }

    // Widget admin form
    ?>
    <p>
    <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Title:', 'eyenod' ); ?></label> 
    <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $title ); ?>" />
    </p>
    <div class="toplist-field-container">
                <ol class="eyenodtoplistitem" style="padding: 10px 0px;">
        <?php if(!empty($instance_eyenod_toplist)) { ?>
            <?php foreach($instance_eyenod_toplist AS $eyenod_toplist) { ?>
                <li>
                    <div class="handle" style="height:20px; background:#EAEAEA;"></div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="eyenod_toplist[<?php echo $eyenod_toplist['id']; ?>][id]" value="<?php echo $eyenod_toplist['id']; ?>" />
                    <label for="eyenod_toplist_imgurl">Image URL:</label><input class="widefat" type="text" name="eyenod_toplist[<?php echo $eyenod_toplist['id']; ?>][imgurl]" value="<?php echo $eyenod_toplist['imgurl']; ?>" /><br />
                    <label for="eyenod_toplist_bonus">Bonus:</label><input class="widefat" type="text" name="eyenod_toplist[<?php echo $eyenod_toplist['id']; ?>][bonus]" value="<?php echo $eyenod_toplist['bonus']; ?>" /><br />
                    <label for="eyenod_toplist_link">Visit URL:</label><input class="widefat" type="text" name="eyenod_toplist[<?php echo $eyenod_toplist['id']; ?>][link]" value="<?php echo $eyenod_toplist['link']; ?>" /><br />
                    <a class="toplist-remove" href="">[Delete]</a>
                </li>
            <?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>
                </ol>
    </div>
    <div style="padding: 10px 0px;">
        <a class="toplist-add" href="">[Add]</a>
    </div>
<?php 
}
```

OK I put in some alert code while testing to see what HTML is being looped through and it seems that my code is looping through list items that do not exist. I have no idea why this would happen. I want to point out again that this is all being done on the wp-admin/widgets.php page of my WordPress install. I could be wrong, but that may be significant.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Are you properly resetting counter to 0? Maybe try using `<ol>`?

Comment: Changing to ol didnt really do anything. As for the counter, I tried some things, but nothing worked. I currently have it so that every time a block is added or removed, the renumber_blocks function is ran. What seems to be happening now is that the index for jQuerys .each inside that function is not resetting back to 0 before looping through each list item. I tried to just have index = 0; before the loop, but that didnt do anything.

Comment: Is there issues with `tl_count`?

Comment: From what I am seeing in my tests, you should be able to just ignore all code other then the renumber_blocks function and the HTML it connects to. I have edited the code in my post so you can see what I have now. I currently have tl_count just set to 0 because I didn't want to change all the indexes to 0 yet. So tl_count is irrelevant right now. All indexes should get updated through the loop in the renumber_blocks function, if the function was working correctly.

Comment: Can no-one else help? Or have any other way I could do this?

Comment: OK I put in some alert code while testing to see what HTML is being looped through and it seems that my code is looping through list items that do not exist. I have no idea why this would happen. I want to point out again that this is all being done on the wp-admin/widgets.php page of my WordPress install. I could be wrong, but that may be significant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I have found out what was wrong. Previously I did not know that Wordpress stored a copy of the widget form inside the selection area on the left of the page. This is a default version that has no numbered ID, but it does share classes and such that you use in your code. This was the problem because I was looping through list items based on the class of the list. So I added the code Wordpress uses to give each widget a unique ID and just inlined my javascript so I could use that ID as a selector. This also pointed out a few other issues I did not notice before. I was, however, able to fix these new issues and now have working code.

For anyone that needs to know, this is the code that sent me on the right track.

```
$this->get_field_id();
```